# What are Android dialog notifications?

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

I read [an article](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/create-toast-notification-android) that said there are 3 types of notification in Android:

- Toast notifications
- Status bar notifications
- Dialog notifications

I know what status bar notification and toast notifications are, but I don't know about dialog notifications. Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dialog notification is:

A dialog is usually a small window that appears in front of the current Activity. The underlying Activity loses focus and the dialog accepts all user interaction. Dialogs are normally used for notifications and short activities that directly relate to the application in progress.

(See the link below for a graphical example of it)

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html#Dialog